# Flyway Docker Container stuck at "Attaching to flyway"

Tags: docker, flyway

I know I'm missing something but I can't figure out. Flyway container is getting stuck at `Attaching to flyway` ...

#### Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.10.1-slim

WORKDIR /app

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY ./app .
COPY flyway/ /flyway/

COPY init.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

#### docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  clover:
    container_name: clover
    build: .
    command: uvicorn app.main:app --reload --host 0.0.0.0
    volumes:
      - .:/app/
    ports:
      - "8008:8000"
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - flyway

  postgres:
    image: postgres:14.1-alpine
    container_name: postgres
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - pg_data:/var/lib/postgresql
      - ./init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
    ports:
      - "5433:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=clover

  flyway:
    image: flyway/flyway
    container_name: flyway
    command: -url=jdbc:postgresql://clover:5433/ -schemas=polk_housing -user=postgres -password=postgres -connectRetries=60 migrate
    volumes:
      - ./flyway/sql:/flyway/sql
    depends_on:
      - postgres

volumes:
    pg_data:
```

So, When I run `docker-compose up -d` it appears that all is good:

```bash
Creating postgres ... done
Creating flyway   ... done
Creating clover   ... done
```

but the fly logs are empty because of the following. After I run the `postgres` and `clover` services separately, I run `docker-compose up flyway` and I get this

```bash
$ docker-compose up flyway
postgres is up-to-date
Creating flyway ... done
Attaching to flyway
```

... and nothing happening.

Can't find a solution for this. I'm sure this is related to the `volumes` section of the `flyway` service in `docker-compose-yml` but I can't figure it out. I've tried every combination of `- ./flyway/sql:/flyway/sql` to mount. Nothing worked.

Comment: It looks like the database URL is wrong: you're trying to connect to the application container and not the database container, and on the wrong port.  I'd be surprised if this caused the migration to just hang rather than report an error, but does using the correct URL `jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432` help at all?

Comment: @DavidMaze yup that was it. Thank you for noticing that. Do u wanna write that as an answer so I can accept it?